# Launch a process without parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, google-chrome, command-line-interface

I am trying to launch chrome from a NodeJS script. When I launch it, the terminal becomes the parent process for chrome. This means that all the permissions for chrome are inherited from terminal process, which means that if I join a video call on chrome, my terminal should have permission for the camera.

Is there a way that I can achieve the desired effect without parent-child relationship? Goal is to launch chrome from a NodeJS script and have it use chrome's own permissions. Here's the code that I am using for it.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

try {
    const executablePath = `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`;
    const flags = [`--remote-debugging-port=12345`];
    const subprocess = spawn(executablePath, flags, {
        detached: true,
        stdio: `ignore`,
    });
    subprocess.unref();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

To check for parent-child relationship on mac, you can visit Activity Monitor and look for Chrome inside terminal.[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot showing chrome as child process of terminal]

Clarification on intent:

The intent is to launch chrome on-demand (from another program) and ensure that it uses it's own permissions rather than inheriting permissions of the program that launched it.

Comment: I guess your real intent is more 'launch chrome with impersonation' more than launch a process with no parent PID ?

Comment: No, the intent is to launch chrome on-demand (from another program) and ensure that it uses it's own permissions rather than inheriting permissions of the program that launched it.

Comment: Try to run chrome app with `nohup`